# could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[...]

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to write some use cases for Apache Flink. One error I run into pretty often is

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[SomeType]
```

My problem is that I cant really nail down when they happen and when they dont.

The most recent example of this would be the following

```
...
val largeJoinDataGen = new LargeJoinDataGen(dataSetSize, dataGen, hitRatio)
val see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val newStreamInput = see.addSource(largeJoinDataGen)
...
```

where `LargeJoinDataGen extends GeneratorSource[(Int, String)]` and `GeneratorSource[T] extends SourceFunction[T]`, both defined in separate files.

When trying to build this I get

```
Error:(22, 39) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[(Int, String)]
val newStreamInput = see.addSource(largeJoinDataGen)
```

**1. Why is there an error in the given example?**

**2. What would be a general guideline when these errors happen and how to avoid them in the future?**

P.S.: first scala project and first flink project so please be patient

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This mostly happens when you have user code, i.e. a source or a map function or something of that nature that has a generic parameter. In most cases you can fix that by adding something like

```
implicit val typeInfo = TypeInformation.of(classOf[(Int, String)])
```

If your code is inside another method that has a generic parameter you can also try adding a context bound to the generic parameter of the method, as in

```
def myMethod[T: TypeInformation](input: DataStream[Int]): DataStream[T] = ...
```

Comment: this solution seems to work. the method call is `TypeInformation.of(classOf[(Int, String)])`, you may want to fix that in your answer.

Answer (score 61):

You may make an import instead of implicits

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
```

It will also help.

Comment: This answer is the better one because it avoids to create TypeInformation implicit lot of time if the flink process is complex :)

Comment: Why does it work? importing every thing from a package seems an anti-pattern

Comment: Why it doesn't work for me? I have `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._` and still getting this error. I'm using flink 1.12.2.

Comment: Strange, the package object looks exactly the same in 1.11.3 which works while 1.12.3 doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

> My problem is that I cant really nail down when they happen and when they dont.

They happen when an [*implicit parameter*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html) is required. If we look at the method definition we see:

```
def addSource[T: TypeInformation](function: SourceFunction[T]): DataStream[T]
```

But we don't see any implicit parameter defined, where is it?

When you see a polymorphic method where the type parameter is of the form

```
def foo[T : M](param: T)
```

Where `T` is the type parameter and `M` is a [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html). It means that the creator of the method is requesting an implicit parameter of type `M[T]`. It is equivalent to:

```
def foo[T](param: T)(implicit ev: M[T])
```

In the case of your method, it is actually expanded to:

```
def addSource[T](function: SourceFunction[T])(implicit evidence: TypeInformation[T]): DataStream[T]
```

This is why you see the compiler complaining, as it can't find the implicit parameter the method is requiring.

If we go to the Apache Flink Wiki, under [Type Information](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Type+System,+Type+Extraction,+Serialization) we can see why this happens :

> ## No Implicit Value for Evidence Parameter Error

> In the case where `TypeInformation` could not be created, programs fail to compile with an error stating *“could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TypeInformation”.*
> A frequent reason if that the code that generates the `TypeInformation` has not been imported. **Make sure to import the entire flink.api.scala package.
> import org.apache.flink.api.scala._**

For generic methods, you'll need to require them to generate a `TypeInformation` at the call-site as well:

> For generic methods, the data types of the function parameters and return type may not be the same for every call and are not known at the site where the method is defined. The code above will result in an error that not enough implicit evidence is available.
> In such cases, the type information has to be generated at the invocation site and passed to the method. Scala offers implicit parameters for that.

Note that `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._` may also be necessary.

For your types this means that if the invoking method is generic, it also needs to request the context bound for it's type parameter.

Comment: `org.apache.flink.api.scala._` was already imported and it still happens. Thats what I meant with "cant nail down".

Comment: @jheyd Require `GeneratorSource[T]` and `SourceFunction[T]` to have context bounds as well:  `GeneratorSource[T : TypeInformation]`, `SourceFunction[T : TypeInformation]`

Comment: SourceFunction is a java interface required by the addSource method, adding context bounds to GeneratorSource did not change anything.

Comment: @jheyd Then perhaps it needs to be available at a closer scope. Is the method calling tge flink API also generic?

Comment: import org.apache.flink.api.scala._ works for me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For example Scala versions (2.11, 2.12, etc.) are not binary compatible.

The following is a wrong configuration even if you use `import org.apache.flink.api.scala._` :

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>
```

Correct configuration in Maven:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.12.8</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
    </properties>
```